# Getting RFKK_MA_SCHEDULER parameter values

Tags: parameters, report, abap, sap-erp, function-module

Anyone who is familiar on how to get the parameters from SAP standard transactions? Variant is currently saved and is being passed and executed at **RFKK_MA_SCHEDULER** I need to collect the ranges on parameter to edit it on runtime.

Function module **FKK_FPYM_READ_PARAMETERS** is being used at Event 1906 to get parameters/ranges that are set then I will do some Select statements that will make my own list and I will use **FKK_AKTIV2_PARA_BASICS_TO_DB** to update the parameter and enter my list instead of the variant template.

This would make the process more optimize. The problem is FM FKK_AKTIV2_PARA_BASICS_TO_DB does not contain parameter "E_ADDONS" from the read parameter FM. Any other workaround?

retrive parameters of new run for modification

```
CALL FUNCTION 'FRK_FEYM READ PARAMETERS'
  EXPORTING
    i_laufd = lv_laufd
    i_laufi = lv_laufi
    i_aktyp = c_aktyp
  IMPORTING
    e_basics = ls basics
    e_addons = ls_addons
  EXCEPTIONS
    not_found = 1
    OTHERS = 2.

  SELECT SINGLE low
    FROM tvarvc
    INTO @1v_cutoff
    WHERE name = @1c_tvarvc_pyr_cutoff
        AND type = @lc_tvarvc_pyr_cutoff_type.

IF 1 = 1.
  LOOP AT lt_dfkkko INTO ls_dfkkko.
    AT NEW vkont.
      CLEAR 1s_vkont.
    ls_vkont-sign = 'I'.
    ls_vkont-option = 'EQ'.
    ls_vkont-low = ls_dfkkko-vkont.
    APPEND 1s_vkont TO ls_basics-ranges-r_vkont.
    ENDAT.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.

*--update payment run paransters in memory and DB
CALL FUNCTION 'FKK_AKTIV2_PARA_BASICS_TO_DB'
  EXPORTING
    i_aktyp = c_aktyp
    i laufd = e_laufd
    i_laufi = e_laufi
    i_basics = ls_basics
  EXCEPTIONS
    unexpected_error = 1
    OTHERS = 2

IF sy-subrc <> 0.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: Don't assume all standard transactions in ABAP-based ERP software all work the same. Only a very small portion are based on the FI-CA module "FKK" layer. Could you provide an example of what you want to retrieve (e.g. screenshot), what should be the input and output values? Can you explain why you are talking about the internal objects `RKK_MA_SCHEDULER` and `FKK_FPYM_READ_PARAMETERS`, and possibly show what code you tried and what is the result? (NB: there is not a single reference about them in sap.com)

Comment: `to edit it on runtime` which runtime? describe your flow how do you gonna modify/reuse **RFKK_MA_SCHEDULER** params, in which program or at what moment

Comment: Hi guys I have added some information is my process clear?